# How does an app like Banjo retrieve social media posts from an event

Tags: facebook, twitter, geolocation, location, instagram

Its most likely some complex algorithm but I was curious if there is an easy solution to do this? I could check the location with a radius but that wouldn't be 100% accurate. I could also use hashtags in twitter/instagram but is there some complete solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some meta data on the event itself, like Foursquare venue ID and start/end time of the event. Then you can pull in Instagram pictures based on the Foursquare ID using this endpoint and then filter by time: https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/514276/media/recent?access_token=...